# How to check array of arrays for my game

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am making a board game where each spot is a button. Everything works like it should other than I want to detect wins. My board is 5 spaces high and 4 wide. so 20 buttons. They are titled like:

```
0   1   2   3

4   5   6   7

8   9   10  11

12  13  14  15

16  17  18  19
```

I have made an array of arrays containing all of the possible wins. Buttons have images on them of pieces and you have to get three in a row. Here is my array of arrays of wins

```
                            // horizontal wins
var winList: [[Int]] = [    [0,1,2],    [1,2,3],
                            [4,5,6],    [5,6,7],
                            [8,9,10],   [9,10,11],
                            [12,13,14], [13,14,15],
                            [16,17,18], [17,18,19],

                            // vertical wins
                            [0,4,8],    [4,8,12],   [8,12,16],
                            [1,5,9],    [5,9,13],   [9,13,17],
                            [2,6,10],   [6,10,14],  [10,14,18],
                            [3,7,11],   [7,11,15],  [11,15,19],

                            // right diagonal wins
                            [2,5,8],    [3,6,9],    [6,9,12],
                            [7,10,13],  [10,13,16], [11,14,17],

                            // left diagonal wins
                            [1,6,11],   [0,5,10],   [5,10,15],
                            [4,9,14],   [9,14,19],  [8,13,18]]
```

I have an empty function called `checkForWin`. How can I make it check to see if Any of the titled buttons match one of the patterns in the winList. In order to win, they should all have the same image on the button.

I did a similar thing earlier with legal moves. I had an array of arrays. Here was my function before:

```
func checkIfValidMove(moveFromButton: UIButton, moveToButton: UIButton) -> Bool {
        var moveFromButtonTitle = moveFromButton.currentTitle
        var moveToButtonTitle = moveToButton.currentTitle
        var moveFromButtonTitleInt = moveFromButtonTitle?.toInt()
        var moveToButtonTitleInt = moveToButtonTitle?.toInt()
        if moveToButton.imageView!.image != UIImage(named:"NoPiece.png") {
            return false
        } else {
            if contains(moveList[moveFromButtonTitleInt!], moveToButtonTitleInt!) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
```

and here was my variable of legal moves:

```
var moveList: [[Int]] = [   [1,4],      [0,2,5],        [1,3,6],        [2,7],
                            [0,5,8],    [1,4,6,9],      [2,5,7,10],     [3,6,11],
                            [4,9,12],   [5,8,10,13],    [6,9,11,14],    [7,10,15],
                            [8,13,16],  [9,12,14,17],   [10,13,15,18],  [11,14,19],
                            [12,17],    [13,16,18],     [14,17,19],     [15,18]]
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: that is a horrible way of defining how to win. you should define something more dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huang Chen's comment made me think about more clever way how to do it, than just defining huge arrays. The problem with your solution is obvious - if you will ever want to increase size of gaming board OR just change dimensions, you will have to rebuild your definition files. Also, when increasing number of "buttons", the number of possible combinations will grow exponentially. Of course what it means is that you will have to do insane number of iterations just for small boards, let alone for something like 10x10.

**Patterns**

But think about this different way, what if you can find pattern in your definitions? Then, it would make it much more easier. When you see your definitions, are there some similarities? Yes, there are!

- Everything seems to be in ascending order, that is good start
- Everything increases by the same amount!
- For horizontal wins, everything must be on the same row and there must be 1 difference between numbers
- For vertical wins, everything must be on the same column and there must be 4 difference between numbers
- For diagonals, those must be sequence with difference of 3 or 5, and it also has to have sequence of the rows, so numbers each start on the next row and only on the next row

So when you see that this holds true for every pattern but it is also not true for all others, and you can clearly see that everything is just simple additive sequence, can we make algorithm, that would check all the pattern and not use your definitions? We need few methods for that:

**Check that numbers are in sequence:**

```
func isSequence3(selection : [Int], allowedDifference : Int) -> Bool {

    // Check if difference between [10] is the same as [21], which makes sequence. Also, check for value of that difference
    let difference10 = selection[1] - selection[0]
    let difference21 = selection[2] - selection[1]
    return difference10 == difference21 && difference10 == allowedDifference
}
```

**Check that numbers are on different rows, consecutive:**

```
func isRowSequence(selection : [Int], rowSize : Int) -> Bool {

    var currentRow = (selection[0] / rowSize) - 1
    for number in selection {
        // Check if row is increasing by one in each step, if yes, remember last row
        if number / rowSize - currentRow == 1 {
            currentRow++
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    // It is row Sequence
    return true
}
```

**Check that numbers are on the same row, and on the same column:**

```
func isOnSameRow(selection : [Int], rowSize : Int) -> Bool {

    return selection.first! / rowSize == selection.last! / rowSize
}


func isOnSameColumn(selection : [Int], columnSize : Int) -> Bool {

    let column = selection.first! % columnSize
    for number in selection {
        if number % columnSize != column {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Now that we have every method we need, we just need validation method to bring all those rules together:

```
func isValidPattern(selection : [Int]) -> Bool {

    // Sort user selection first, ascending
    var ascSelection = selection.sorted(ascending)

    // Validate for horizontal wins
    let isValidForHorizontalWins = self.isSequence3(ascSelection, allowedDifference: 1)
                                && self.isOnSameRow(ascSelection, rowSize: ROW_SIZE)

    // Validate for vertical wins
    let isValidForVerticalWins = self.isSequence3(ascSelection, allowedDifference: 4)
                             && self.isOnSameColumn(ascSelection, columnSize: COLUMN_SIZE)

    // Validate for diagonals
    let isValidForDiagonals =  self.isSequence3(ascSelection, allowedDifference: 3)
                            || self.isSequence3(ascSelection, allowedDifference: 5)
                            && self.isRowSequence(ascSelection, rowSize: ROW_SIZE)

    // Is at least one rule valid?
    return isValidForHorizontalWins || isValidForVerticalWins || isValidForDiagonals
}
```

And that's it (or at least I think it should be, considering how late it is, I will review tomorrow just to be sure :) Anyway, [here is complete gist](https://gist.github.com/JiriTrecak/907588b8b38812c1ba14) with all codes together. By adjusting numbers in validation method, you could make it work for any size you want. There are also optimizations to be done, but that is for you.

**Some tips at the end:**

- Always search for solutions that are dynamic. At the end, it will save you big amount of time (trying to figure out all the combinations.. not fun)
- I am using Ints as you probably noticed. UIButton has .tag variable, where you can assign numbers. This way, you can easily identify buttons not by image, but by tag, which in your case makes this whole solution much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the name of an image from a `UIImage`, so I would subclass UIButton so that you can have a field for the name of the image being shown on that button. After that, just use a double `for` loop and check the image names of all the buttons.

```
for win in winList
{
    let name = buttons[win[0]].imageName  //imageName is the field in the UIButton subclass
    var won = true

    //make sure all the buttons in the win have the same name
    for i in 1..<win.count
    {
        if !buttons[win[i]].imageName.isEqualToString(name)
        {
            won = false
            break
        }
    }

    if won
    {
        //do something because a win has been achieved
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! and i already figured out how to get name of image. Thanks for your help!

Comment: While it works, it is very bad practice and one you should not follow. You shouldn't subclass UI components to store information for you. You should use .tag to identify by number or use some data structure that would store that information for you.